# j2me SDK3 for AWT/Swing application

Tags: java-me

I try to development an embedded application with Eclipse + J2me SDK3 + CDC.

When I am trying to create a Frame or JFrame, there is an error says "Could not read environment variable SUBLIME-PROC-ID".

Who know what's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get a J2ME plugin for Eclipse, but I have found that doing J2ME development is easier using Netbeans.

I haven't use a frame in J2ME, but you may want to just use a Canvas.

Here is a relatively simple example of doing some frame animation on J2ME.

http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/frame-animation.shtml

If you are using the Personal Profile then you can develop much as you would with JavaSE, but I don't know if you are going with that.

**UPDATE:**

Toward the end of this post a comment was made that SUBLIME-PROC-ID was defined in a bash configuration file, and when that was removed the error went away.

You may have it defined somewhere in one of your configuration files, so you may want to look for that. I have never heard of this environment variable, so you may want to change your tags to have something about *run-configuration* or something in it, to help others out.
http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=353367

Comment: I am not going to do some phone development. I just want to do some embedded application which with AWT or Swing or SWT GUI.

It is ok when it runs in Eclipse environment.
But When it runs without the eclipse, the problem is "Could not read environment variable SUBLIME-PROC-ID". (I run it under the CDC environment)

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to do some phone development.

I just want to do some embedded application which with AWT or Swing or SWT GUI. It is ok when it runs in Eclipse environment.

But When it runs without the eclipse, the problem is "Could not read environment variable SUBLIME-PROC-ID". (I run it under the CDC environment)